# Testing Zoho Mail server from ssh

Tags: email, ssh, mail-server, zoho

I want to ensure our server able to connect and send emails using Zoho's service. How do I test this purely via terminal connected to my server's ssh?

Server's setting is Linux Ubuntu but a platform agnostic answer would be most appreciated.

Following is Zoho's mail server details:
https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/zoho-smtp.html

Answer (score 2):

Connect to smtp.zoho.com on the port 25 for establishing smtp connection and send mails. For SSL/TLS connections, openssl library should be used for establishing smtp connection

For simple smtp connection

```
telnet smtp.zoho.com 25
```

For SSL connection

```
openssl s_client -connect smtp.zoho.com:465
```

For TLS connection

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.zoho.com:587 -crlf -ign_eof
```

Hope this suffices